# How to convert string to ascii byte array in php

Tags: php, laravel

How to convert string to ascii Byte Array??

I want to integrate propay payment gateway to my code to create merchant account and its not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an old post now but for anyone else that comes across this in the future like me:

In PHP, strings are already byte arrays. So to put together the auth header for ProPay, see the following example:

```
$certStr = 'MyCertStr';
$termId = 'MyTermId';
$base64 = base64_encode($certStr.':'.$termId);
$authorization = 'Basic '.$base64;
//Output: "Basic TXlDZXJ0U3RyOk15VGVybUlk"
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function convert_string_to_byte_array($input_string) {
    $byte_array = $input_string;
    return $byte_array;
}
```